# Python Sentiment Analysis given a dataset with Facebook Posts

Tags: python, label, nltk, data-mining, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataset containing raw facebook posts and comments. What I would like to do is to perform sentiment analysis with Python 3 (NTLK ?) in order to label each post and each comment against some categories (a sort of clustering in unsupervised mode). The problem is that I have no idea how to do something similar.

I accept suggestions
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [vaderSentiment](https://pypi.org/project/vaderSentiment/) which is a python package to perform unsupervised English Sentiment Analysis using dictionary and rules. There is some example on their [github](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment#code-examples). This option might be more effective than an unsupervised clustering.

Comment: This is a great improvement. But what if the posts are in another language (e.g. Italian) ?

Comment: you could use a model that is already trained to perform sentiment analysis on Italian language in order to classify your texts. For example, there is a pre-trained BERT for multilingual sentiment analysis which is including the Italian language. You can find it here: https://huggingface.co/nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment

Comment: Thank you very much. It's time to study something new !

Comment: Indeed, the Transformer is an innovative architecture that has revolutionized NLP. There are resources on the internet that popularize the subject. Have fun learning!